# Docker remote access

Tags: docker, ssl, ssl-certificate

I followed [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#use-tls-https-to-protect-the-docker-daemon-socket) in order to access a remote docker (installed on a server B) daemon from a server A.

So, all certificates were generated on server B and copied in the docker client machine, server A.

I had already tested the remote access by running the following command :

```
docker  --tlsverify  -H=$MY_HOST:$MY_PORT  
        --tlscacert=$MY_PATH/ca.pem 
        --tlscert=$MY_PATH/client-cert.pem 
        --tlskey=$MY_PATH/client-key.pem
```

Everything is looking good so far, and I had succefully access the remote docker daemon.

However, when I tried to access it by exporting Docker envrionment variables

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://MY_HOST:$MY_PORT  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 DOCKER_CERT_PATH=~/certs
```

things don't turn out as expected (tls: bad certificate) :

```
The server probably has client authentication (--tlsverify) enabled. Please check your TLS client certification settings: Get https://MY_HOST:MY_PORT/v1.40/containers/json?all=1: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`DOCKER_CERT_PATH` is a directory prefix. It assumes that there are individual files of fixed names under that path: `ca.pem`, `cert.pem`, and `key.pem`.

Try something similar to this:

```bash
tmp="$(mktemp --directory)"
cp "${MY_PATH}/ca.pem" "${tmp}/ca.pem"
cp "${MY_PATH}/client-cert.pem" "${tmp}/cert.pem"
cp "${MY_PATH}/client-key.pem" "${tmp}/key.pem"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="${tmp}" DOCKER_HOST="tcp://${MY_HOST}:${MY_PORT}/" DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=true
docker ps --all
```

It's also worth noting that the default path is `~/.docker/`; the expected files can be created there, if it matches your use case.